# Github Actions shows error despite passing

Tags: github-actions

When trying to setup github actions for my **private** repository I'm getting strange output where the github action succeeds but each step shows up with just `Error:`  in red. This is proving rather annoying because I'm not able to actually view what went wrong in the case of an actual error without viewing the raw logs.

[Example screenshot showing error text in the github action page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7OCO.png)

(The warning in that screenshot is for the `ubuntu-latest` updating to `2020.04` soon)

Here's the workflow file:

```yaml
name: Build and Verify

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [14]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

      - run: npm ci

      - name: Lint
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Prettier Check
        run: npm run pretty-check
```

The only thing of note in the raw logs are the various control characters, but I'm unsure if they're causing the issue. I tried to remove them, but even running something as simple as `echo "test"` causes them to be output.

```
2021-02-02T05:39:30.2089718Z ##[group]Run npm ci
2021-02-02T05:39:30.2090246Z [36;1mnpm ci[0m
2021-02-02T05:39:30.2138413Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2021-02-02T05:39:30.2138894Z ##[endgroup]
2021-02-02T05:39:38.6616638Z added 339 packages in 4.344s
2021-02-02T05:39:38.6846225Z ##[group]Run npm run lint
2021-02-02T05:39:38.6846719Z [36;1mnpm run lint[0m
2021-02-02T05:39:38.6892402Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2021-02-02T05:39:38.6892832Z ##[endgroup]
```

I've tried searching for similar issues but am unable to find any.